# Google Maps Javascript API v3 dynamic markers slightly off in location and gets worse zooming in or out

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map which I am trying to generate dynamic markers for. Here is the relevent code. Any help would be greatly appreciated! also, I removed my key. The markers are all slightly off position and it gets worse when I zoom in or out.

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"
                    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_HERE">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function initialize() {
                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: { lat: 38.989260, lng: -77.076198},
                        zoom: 13
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                        mapOptions);
load_markers(map);
                }
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>
            <script>
                function load_markers(map){



                    var myLatlng_0 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.898702, -77.15228400000001);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_0 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_0,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_0.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.911023, -77.19537200000002);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_1,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_1.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_2 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.897052, -77.14111500000001);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_2,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_2.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_3 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.8964079, -77.184057);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_3 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_3,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_3.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_4 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.8964019, -77.1840694);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_4 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_4,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_4.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_5 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.875528, -77.12865699999998);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_5 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_5,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_5.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_6 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.89987, -77.26557600000001);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_6 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_6,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_6.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_7 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.895214, -77.11174799999998);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_7 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_7,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_7.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_8 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.894044, -77.25868100000002);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_8 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_8,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_8.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_9 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.89598100000001, -77.18421599999999);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_9 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_9,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_9.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_10 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.895918, -77.26371499999999);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_10 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_10,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_10.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_11 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.89458, -77.263038);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_11 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_11,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_11.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_12 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.896569, -77.16078900000002);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_12 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_12,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_12.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_13 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.904719, -77.27201400000001);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_13 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_13,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_13.setMap(map)

                    var myLatlng_14 = new google.maps.LatLng(38.8788259, -77.10319500000003);
                    // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
                    var marker_14 = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng_14,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'click to zoom'
                    });
                    marker_14.setMap(map)
                                    }
            </script>
```

Can anyone tell me the issue with this code? I have removed the key. The markers are pretty close to the right location but when I zoom they dont stay. It's like they need to re-render or be anchored. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How do we tell where they are _supposed_ to be?  Looking at [this fiddle created from the posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/0e7tcd1c/), the markers don't move when I zoom in or out.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, your jsfiddle is how it is supposed to look. On my page it moves as I zoom in or out though. The lat and longs are correct, my rendering is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function that places the markers.

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: 38.989260, lng: -77.076198},
        zoom: 13
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
    load_markers(map);
}
```

---

Edit: I'm seeing very weird behavior on your linked demo. Try this:

```
var mapOptions = {
  ...
  center: new google.maps.LatLng({38.989260, -77.076198}),
  ...
}
```

edit2: nevermind, the docs say the literal objects are fine here...

Comment: This worked, but the markers are slightly off in position and when I zoom in or out it gets worse. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you don't want the default anchor point of 'bottom center' and maybe also you need more precision on the lat/lng values

Comment: The latitude is to the 6th decimal which is really small.(wikipedia says thats roughly the size of a human). I am using the default marker so shouldn't it already be set to scale appropriately?

Comment: yeah. it should work fine as is. any chance you've deployed this somewhere public like cloud 9 so we can look further?

Comment: I guess you could try calling `map.on('zoomChanged', function(){ marker.setMap() });` but i don't remember having to do anything special to update these when the map redraws...

Comment: any chance the javascript exception thrown by the slideshow script is breaking the map? i'm otherwise stumped!

Comment: the CSS of the parent div :( Sorry gang! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but just in case someone else is having the same issue, the problem as I found it was that the coordinates used in the Google Maps URL ***are that of the centre of the map*** as it's drawn in that instance, ***not the coordinates of the address that's been searched***.

So if you're using a dynamically created map, these coordinates won't pinpoint an address, instead you'll have to use something like http://www.latlong.net to get the true latitude and longitude.